# App not setup: This app is still in development mode - Login through Facebook 2021

Tags: flutter, facebook-login, flutter-facebook-login

I'm trying to create a Login through Facebook button in my Flutter project using Firebase. I added all the things Facebook asked and I have also set my app in **Live mode**. But when I try to Login, it says

> App not setup: This app is still in development mode.

Here's the code I've used in my flutter project:

```
Future<UserCredential> _signInWithFacebook() async {
    final AccessToken result = await FacebookAuth.instance.login();

    final FacebookAuthCredential facebookAuthCredential =
      FacebookAuthProvider.credential(result.token);

    return await FirebaseAuth.instance.signInWithCredential(facebookAuthCredential);
  }
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: try unstalling and then reinstall the app might work

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work

Comment: Have you found the solution?